# Command Line app for calculating payroll in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, console, formatting

I had an assignment last semester to program a payroll app utilizing methods. I went back to it and re-wrote it to include an extra class as well. I would like some feedback regarding whether my code is following the Single Responsibility SOLID principle - should the class be split further into more classes?

I would also like some tips on how I could format the output nicer using printf as depending on how long the names or pay are, the columns get misaligned.

Here is the code:

````
//Java payroll program utilizing methods and classes

import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Payroll
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {  
      //declaration block
      Payroll app = new Payroll();   
      int SIZE;
      double overtimeEarnings = 0.0;
      double averageGross = 0.0;
      double totalGross = 0.0;
      
      //taxes and fees constants 
      final double fTax = 0.12;
      final double sTax = 0.06;
      final double uFees = 0.01;
  
      double sentinel = 0.0;
      
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Payroll Calculator\n");
      
      do {
            System.out.println("How many employees?: ");
            SIZE = kb.nextInt();
            Employees dataHousing = new Employees(SIZE);

            
            dataHousing.input();
            dataHousing.calculateGross();
            dataHousing.calculateNet(sTax, fTax, uFees);
            
            
            totalGross = app.calculateTotalGross(dataHousing.grossPay, SIZE);
            averageGross = app.calculateAverageGross(totalGross, SIZE);
            app.output(dataHousing, totalGross, averageGross, SIZE);
            
            //clear after output in case user wants to repeat program
            totalGross = 0.0;
            averageGross = 0.0;
            
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter 1 to repeat the program, any other number to quit");
            sentinel = app.input();
            
            }
      while(sentinel == 1);
      
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
   
   
   }
   double input()
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      double value;
      value = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
      
      return value;
   }
   double calculateTotalGross( double gIncome[], final int SIZE)
   {
         double totalGross = 0.0;

         for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
         {  
            totalGross += gIncome[i];
                     
         }
   
         return totalGross;
   }
   
  double calculateAverageGross(double tGross, final int SIZE)
  {   
            
      return tGross/SIZE;
   
  }

  void output(Employees x,double tGross, double aGross, final int SIZE)
  {
         System.out.printf("%70s%n", "Data Housing Corp. Payroll");
         System.out.printf("%110s%n","__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
         System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s%n", "First Name |" , "M Initial |" , "Surname |" , "Rate/h |" , "OT Hours |" , 
                                    "Gross $ |" , "State Tax |" , "Fed Tax |" , "Union fees |"  , "Net $ |");
                  
         for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
         {
            System.out.printf("%5s %8s %15s %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f %10.2f%n%n",x.firstName[i] , x.MI[i] , x.lastName[i] , 
            x.payRate[i] , x.overtimeHours[i] , x.grossPay[i], x.stateTax[i] , + x.fedTax[i] , x.unionFees[i] , x.netPay[i]);

         }
                    
          System.out.printf("Total Gross is: %.2f%n" , tGross);
          System.out.printf("Average Gross is: %.2f%n" , aGross);
          
  }
}
class Employees
{
   String[] firstName;
   String[] lastName;
   char[] MI;
   double[] hours;
   double[] overtimeHours;
   double[] payRate;
   double[] grossPay;
   double[] netPay;
   double[] stateTax;
   double[] fedTax;
   double[] unionFees;
   
   final int SIZE;
   
   Employees(int SIZE)
   {  
      this.SIZE = SIZE;
      this.firstName = new String[SIZE];
      this.lastName = new String[SIZE];
      this.MI = new char[SIZE];
      this.hours = new double[SIZE];
      this.payRate = new double[SIZE];
      this.grossPay = new double[SIZE];
      this.overtimeHours = new double[SIZE];
      this.netPay = new double[SIZE];
      this.stateTax = new double[SIZE];
      this.fedTax = new double[SIZE];
      this.unionFees = new double[SIZE];
   }
  
   void input()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter the First Name: ");
         firstName[i] = keyboard();
                                   
         System.out.println("Please enter the Middle Initial: ");
         MI[i] = keyboard().charAt(0);
                           
         System.out.println("Please enter the Last Name: ");
         lastName[i] = keyboard();
               
         System.out.println("Please enter the hours worked: ");
         hours[i] = Double.parseDouble(keyboard());
            
         System.out.println("Please enter the hourly pay rate: ");
         payRate[i] = Double.parseDouble(keyboard());
       } 
   }
      
   String keyboard()
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      String value;
      value = kb.nextLine();
      
      return value;
   }
/**  
*  gross method calculates the gross income of each employee and stores the value in grossPay member
*
*  
*/    
   void calculateGross()
   {  
      double overtimeEarnings;
      for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
         if(hours[i] > 40) 
         {
            overtimeHours[i] = hours[i] - 40;
            overtimeEarnings = overtimeHours[i] * (payRate[i] * 1.5);
            grossPay[i] = ((hours[i] - overtimeHours[i]) * payRate[i]) + overtimeEarnings;
            
         }else {
                  overtimeHours[i] = 0.0;
                  grossPay[i] = hours[i] * payRate[i];
               }
       }
       
    }
/**  
*  Calculate Net method calculates the net pay  of each employee after taxes and stores it in netPay member
*
*  @param sT = stateTax
*  @param fT = fedTax
*  @param uF = unionFees
*/ 

    void calculateNet(final double sT,final double fT, final double uF)
    {     

      for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
         stateTax[i] = grossPay[i] * sT;
         fedTax[i] = grossPay[i] * fT;
         unionFees[i] = grossPay[i] * uF;
         netPay[i] = grossPay[i] - (stateTax[i] + fedTax[i] + unionFees[i]);
      
      }
    }


}

```
````

Comment: bump :(((((((((

Comment: Give us time to answer. Reviewing a code and writing a polite, well described and useful answer take time.

Comment: @gervais.b didn't mean to rush! I'm new to the forum and wasn't sure if anyone would answer after so many hours.

Answer (score 2):

So, you would like to know if your code is *"following the Single Responsibility
SOLID principle"*. *S.O.L.I.D.* stand for *Single responsibility*,
*Open-closed principle*, *Liskov substitution principle*, *Interface segregation*
and *Dependency Inversion*.

### Single responsibility

*One class have a single responsibility*. But both `Payroll` and `Employees` are
mixing business logic, IOs and datas.

### Open-closed principle

*Classes should be open for extension but closed for modification*. This is not
easily applicable in your case.

Try to implement different way to compute the payroll.

### Liskov substitution

*Classes should be replaceable with subtypes*. This one is not applicable because
there are no inheritance in your code.

### Interface segregation

*Client should not depend on interfaces they don't use*. Like for the previous,
this one is not easily applicable in a small system.

### Dependency Inversion

*Depend on abstraction*. Once again, this is not easily applicable in a small
system. But one way will be to pass your `Employees` to `Payroll` instead of
creating the instance. By doing that you can easily imagine to have another
implementation of your `Employess`.

---

You also want some tips on formatting but you are already using `printf`. However
your column are still missaligned due to different name length.

One solution would be to compute the minimum length of your columns to build the
formatting pattern.